# How do I utilize builder from several options in scala

Tags: scala, immutability

I'm using a Java library in my Scala code and have to utilize some builder:

```
val buildResult = new Builder()
  .withPropertyA(a)
  .withPropertyB(b)
  .withPropertyC(c)
  .build()
```

What if I have `bOption` and `cOption` as `Option`s enclosing `b` and `c` and don't want methods `withPropertyB` and `withPropertyC` to be called if corresponding values are `None`.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: The usual way that I have seen would be to create a Scala version of the builder (possibly wrapping the original builder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent interfaces, especially Java ones, usually rely on mutation so the idiomatic way would be to wrap it in pure interface.

However, you could (ab)use the in-place mutation to do something like:

```
val builder = new Builder()
bOption.foreach(builder.withPropertyB)
cOption.foreach(builder.withPropertyC)
val buildResult = builder.build()
```

Comment: buildResult is not a builder, it is result of new Builder().build()

Comment: Well, I don't think it should change how it is used. I've update the naming to make it clearer.